# Pdf to image converter without ghostscript

Tags: c#, node.js, pdf, converters

I am looking for a dotnet / nodejs library to convert pdf to image (to be used as a thumbnail). I know there are loads of disucssion already been done on this topic but most of them use ghost script which I can not use as because it's license terms (GNU GPL).

there are some online services as well but the pdfs are confidencial, so I have no liberty to use them.

I am looking for MIT or Apache license Or do not mind paid version of API.  does any one used or know such library/API ?

Comment: Ghostscript is AGPL, so you can buy commercial license if interested. If you do that, you can use Ghostscript.NET ( http://github.com/jhabjan/Ghostscript.NET ) from C#.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at this:

http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/WindowsAPICodePack

You can call ShellObject.FromParsingName("C:\somefolder\somefile.pdf").

Comment: This is 0 cost thumbnail generator and "partially" worked for me, Unfortunately I can not Get the thumbnail when I use this code in WebAPI but the exe does. Sp I have created a command line utility and accessed that in webAPI but that also doesnot work My be the executing context does not allow the preview handler to provide thumbnail.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [Docotic.Pdf library](https://bitmiracle.com/pdf-library/). It is not free but good. And doesn't require you to install any command line tools with viral licenses.

Here is a sample code for a thumbnail generator.

```
using (Stream output = new MemoryStream())
{
    using (PdfDocument pdf = new PdfDocument(@"input.pdf"))
    {
        PdfDrawOptions options = PdfDrawOptions.CreateFitSize(new PdfSize(200, 200), false);
        options.BackgroundColor = new PdfGrayColor(100);
        pdf.Pages[0].Save(output, options);
    }
}
```

More samples for [drawing and printing of PDFs](https://bitmiracle.com/pdf-library/draw-print-pdf) are available on our site.

Disclaimer: I am one of the developers of the library.

Answer (score 0):

Gnostice PDFOne .NET has a saveAsImage method with which you can save PDF page content to a raster image format such as JPEG, BMP, TIFF or PNG.

If you want a vector output, use the getPageMetafile method with which you get a Metafile object. However, the .NET Metafile class does not save to EMF/WMF. You will need to use some unmanaged calls as explained at:
http://www.gnostice.com/nl_article.asp?id=201&t=How_To_Convert_PDF_To_Image_Formats_In_NET

DISCLAIMER: I work for Gnostice.

Answer (score 0):

To get crisp iconic/thumbnail output use PNG as an output.

So to do that in a loop command with a single line there are many options.

My favourite would be to use GhostScript's Sister MuPDF (Mutool) but has same license.

Thus FOSS is poppler so set any width, height, croping and resolution as per desire.

```
pdftoppm -png -scale-to-x 210 -scale-to-y 297 -f 1 -l 1 "JPEG image compression FAQ, part 1_2.pdf" thumb001
```

Here is that default output as requested 200x297 pixels.

[image]